# Running std::thread with different argument function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

is it possible to create N std::thread objects, each running a while loop until the "task" list is not empty ?

It could be look like this:

```
Schedule sched( N );
schned.add( func1, param1, param2, param3 );
schned.add( func1, param1, param2, param3 );

schned.add( func2, param1 );

schned.add( func3, IntegerParam );
schned.add( func4, StringParam );

sched.start(); // start & join each thread wait until all threads finished
```

with function declaration:

```
bool func1( int, int, int );
bool func2( int );
bool func3( int );
bool func4( std::string );
```

is this possible with [variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: @DrewDormann what do i need to store the parameter ? std::initializer_list or variadic arguments ?

Comment: Yes. Its called a thread pool. Its the first thing that anybody learning threads writes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty simple with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) so long as all of the functions have the same return type.

In your `Schedule` class you can just store a `std::queue<std::function<bool()>>`.  Then have `Schedule::add()` look something like this:

```
template<typename func>
Schedule::add(func f) {
    // Appropriate synchronization goes here...
    function_queue.push_front(f);  // Will work as long as func can be converted to std::function<bool()>
}
```

Then you can add tasks like so:

```
Shedule sched(N);
// This works with function pointers
sched.add(someFunctionThatTakesNoArgs);
// And function like objects such as those returned by std::bind
sched.add(std::bind(func1, param1, param2, param3));
sched.add(std::bind(func1, param1, param2, param3));
sched.add(std::bind(func2, param1));
// Even member functions
SomeClass foo;
sched.add(std::bind(SomeClass::func3, foo, IntegerParam));
sched.add(std::bind(SomeClass::func4, foo, StringParam));

sched.start();
```

Then just have your worker threads do something like:

```
Schedule::worker() {
    // Synchronization left as an exercise for the reader...
    while (more_work_to_do) {
        std::function<bool()> f(function_queue.pop_back());
        f();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow! i didn't know something about std::bind! big thanks for the work!

Comment: @Roby: The other thing commonly stored in `std::function` are lambda's: `[param1, param2}() { func1(param1, param2); }`. The advantage is that lambda's allow more complex code: `[param1, param2}() { func1(param1, ) * func2(param2); }`